# I had an update, then project couldn't connect to Web Services.( It drops on catch block)

Tags: android, android-studio, updates, android-ksoap2

I had an update for Android Studio. After it finished, I had a problem with Ksoap2 3.6.2. While I was debugging, it is always in catch block.

To try to solve this I uninstalled Ksoap2 and then installed again. But it still can not connect to Web Services. How can I solve this problem?

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        String resTxt = null;
        try {    
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + webMethName, envelope);// 1.Step and then goes to catch block
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            resTxt = response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {//problem is here
            e.printStackTrace();
            result.Success = 0;
            result.Message = "Error!!!" + e.getMessage();
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: what does `printStackTrace()` say?

Comment: @RahulKhurana  During on debug I see that line, e: "java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to (ıp address comes here) not permitted.

Comment: What is the message you've got inside catch block?

Comment: @RahulKhurana if you ask result.Message, Message is "Error!" that comes from String file by call ksoap. I created it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens because on Android 9 cleartext traffic (http) is restricted by default. What you need to do is add to your manifest:

```
<application
     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

You should avoid using http in production, this is only for development stage.

Comment: Instead of answering obviously duplicate questions, please mark them as duplicates.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Okey, When you wrote once, I can get it. you dont need to say three times. I ask this question because I didnt get the problem about Cleartext HTTP traffic. I am beginner. But even so, thank you, I will be carefull about it next time.

Comment: @esradidembayar this one does not relate to you at all.